# Calendar List View in SharePoint Server 2019

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2019

In SharePoint 2019 I create a calendar by going to: Settings Wheel > Add an app > Calendar

How can I then create a list view for the calendar?  Can this be done by going to Calendar > Edit List, then creating a new view with the list view format?  If so, how?

Or do you need to create a seperate page and add the calendar to that page as a web part, then edit that web part (or something similar)?

By list view I mean a vertical list of calendar items that span from today's date to 12 months in advance.  However, I am less concerned with the specifics of the date range and more concerned with the basic how to.  Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've been using Modern views and pages, the SharePoint calendar is likely very confusing because it still uses the "classic" view, even if the entire rest of your site is using the Modern UI.

- Go open your calendar list to its default view.
- In the upper left-hand corner, click on the small "Calendar" tab (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of Calendar tab]

- This will bring up the calendar "ribbon", and from there you have multiple View options to either edit the current view or create a new one (see screenshot)

[image: Screenshot of Calendar Ribbon]

For more details on List View creation, see https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-change-or-delete-a-view-of-a-list-or-library-27ae65b8-bc5b-4949-b29b-4ee87144a9c9#OfficeVersion=2016,_2013,_2010 -- be sure to not actually look at the version of this page for SP2019, as it assumes you are editing a modern list.